# Attempting - Multithreading - in VB.net Windows Forms

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, delegates, invoke

For a while now i have been using this code:

```vb
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim t2 As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf SetLabelText2)
    t2.IsBackground = True
    t2.Start()
End Sub

Delegate Sub UpdateDelegate()

Private Sub SetLabelText2()
    If InvokeRequired Then
        Invoke(New UpdateDelegate(AddressOf SetLabelText2))
    Else
        For i = 1 To 110
            Label2.Text = Text
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

This code runs fine, except its not Multithreading my Application and puts it into a Unresponsive State.

My Question is simple, 
1.How can i fix this ( The application I will be using will have SEVERAL Function calls within

```vb
If InvokeRequired Then

    Invoke(New UpdateDelegate(AddressOf SetLabelText2))

Else

   FunctionCall1()

   FunctionCall2()

   FunctionCall3()

End If
```

they all work and take ahold of my UI Thread.

I have been searching for quite some time now, any help is appreciated.

-Edit-
Also having issues while in a thread to read information from a form ... :) thanks for the help so far

EDIT ---

Ok, i have change my Code around to look like

```vb
Delegate Sub setForm1PrgBarPerformStepdelegate(s As Integer) 
    Private Sub setForm1PrgBarPerformStep(ByVal s As Integer)
        If Form1.ProgressBar1.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim d As New setForm1lblAlltextdelegate(AddressOf setForm1PrgBarPerformStep)
            Form1.Invoke(d, New Object() {s})
        Else
            If s = 1 Then
            Form1.ProgressBar1.PerformStep()
        Else

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This piece of code is being called with setForm1PrgBarPerformStep(1) ' or 0

Wich is called by my thread, ( It works ( the threading part - witch is awesome btw ), with the minor flaw of NOT doing the Perform Step - or any other UI changes I Code in the Private Sub setForm1PrgBarPerformStep()

Is there a good reason for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your thread first hits SetLabelText2, InvokeRequired will be true so

```
Invoke(New UpdateDelegate(AddressOf SetLabelText2))
```

will be called.

Now, what actually happens inside the Invoke call is that your thread is going to pass the delegate to the UI thread as a task. So the second, recursive call to SetLabelText2 will be done by the UI thread and your thread just sits and waits for the UI thread to return from SetLabelText2. So your UI blocks because the UI thread will be in a loop, setting the label text and sleeping, and doesn't get a chance to process messages/events.

As a solution, instead of Sleep(200) you can call Application.DoEvents() inside your loop, but this may have side effects and is not recommended.

A better solution is to restrict Invoke to the strictly necessary UI calls, in your example:

```
Private Sub SetLabelText2()
    For i = 1 To 110
        'Label2.Text = Text
        Invoke(MyDelegateThatDoesNothingButSettingTheLabelText)
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
    Next
End Sub
```

Now the Sleeping will be done by your thread and your UI remains responsive.

Comment: Aliright, i will attempt this solution as im unaware how im going to invoke all UI calls within the functions that are within my set label text sub ... your saying for every ui im changing ill have to create a seperate sub and invoke them?

Comment: @user2236967 You do not have to create a sub for every single call to a method/setter/getter that requires invoke. You can bundle those calls. Just make sure the methods you `Invoke()` do little work and return quickly because every `Invoke()` call blocks the UI for the time it needs to complete. Have the hard work done inbetween calls to `Invoke()`

Comment: wow thats crappy looking , will be putting this into an edit above

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that the Sleep in SetLabelText2 is being called on the UI thread rather than on the background thread due to the Invoke. This will cause the UI to appear locked. The new thread is only used to launch the SetLabel, but the work is then almost immediately returned to the calling thread. Instead, you need to be calling into the background task inside of your loop and delegating back to the UI for each label update.

Secondly, you shouldn't be creating explicit threads in this example. As of .Net 4, you should be using Tasks instead. To simulate a long running operation as you are doing with the Thread.Sleep, use Task.Delay(200) and then either Await it or call .Wait explicitly on it. Remember to schedule the delay on a background thread and delegate back for the UI updates.

Comment: The Sleep was a solution from someone else, but thanks for the information. ---- My fault , guess i did have a sleep in the top portion of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so thanks to the comments made in this section and the help of some research I finially figured it out.

I kinda cheated alittle bit by Running UI thread and only breaking out to do the heavy work weather it be in a loop or just for a short time, here is some code - hope this helps others.

```
Public t2 As Threading.Thread ' Instantiating the Thread. I do this in my Modules
                              ' You will want to do this for all threads needed.

'You would then go through your program like normal until you hit a heavy process eating point,
'For me it was when i was converting images and sending them / moving them across the network

'So to get what i wanted i used this in the middle of my public Function

    For Each s As String In sFiles
        c += 1 'This was just a simple file counter for the prg bar

CheckAgain:
        If t3 Is Nothing Then
            t3 = New Thread(New ParameterizedThreadStart(AddressOf DoWork))
            t3.Start(s)
            GoTo NextOne
        ElseIf t4 Is Nothing Then
            t4 = New Thread(New ParameterizedThreadStart(AddressOf DoWork))
            t4.Start(s)
            GoTo NextOne
        ElseIf t5 Is Nothing Then
            t5 = New Thread(New ParameterizedThreadStart(AddressOf DoWork))
            t5.Start(s)
            GoTo NextOne
        ElseIf t6 Is Nothing Then
            t6 = New Thread(New ParameterizedThreadStart(AddressOf DoWork))
            t6.Start(s)
            GoTo NextOne
        ElseIf t7 Is Nothing Then
            t7 = New Thread(New ParameterizedThreadStart(AddressOf DoWork))
            t7.Start(s)
            GoTo NextOne
        ElseIf t8 Is Nothing Then
            t8 = New Thread(New ParameterizedThreadStart(AddressOf DoWork))
            t8.Start(s)
            GoTo NextOne
        ElseIf t9 Is Nothing Then
            t9 = New Thread(New ParameterizedThreadStart(AddressOf DoWork))
            t9.Start(s)
            GoTo NextOne
        Else
            GoTo CheckAgain
        End If
NextOne:
    Next

Sub DoWork(ByVal s As Object)

        ChangeCompression("Variables for my Function that did alot of work")
        'System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)

    'This is how i disposed of my threads

    If Not (t3 Is Nothing) Then
        t3 = Nothing
    ElseIf Not (t4 Is Nothing) Then
        t4 = Nothing
    ElseIf Not (t5 Is Nothing) Then
        t5 = Nothing
    ElseIf Not (t6 Is Nothing) Then
        t6 = Nothing
    ElseIf Not (t7 Is Nothing) Then
        t7 = Nothing
    ElseIf Not (t8 Is Nothing) Then
        t8 = Nothing
    ElseIf Not (t9 Is Nothing) Then
        t9 = Nothing
    End If

End Sub
```

And thats all that was too it :) - hope this can help someone , and thanks all for helping me get MY - kinda Multithreading done, yeh ... i know there are better ways but this one works for me :)